# Add products to my supply chain simulation and some problems

Tags: java, anylogic

I would like to add products to my supply chain simulation (Manufacturer, Wholesaler, and Retailers)
To explain more: I created now a simulation of Manufacturer, 2 wholesalers and 10 retailers and I would like to create

- a population of client that orders from retailers by ***Poisson distribution*** **(I don't know how to do it)**
- if the retailer received the order he will check on current stock, if the order available he will fulfil the retailer, if not he'll send an order to the manufacturer.
- the manufacturer has full capacity.

Does anyone tell me how to create this ?
I just made the simulation of moving truck from manufacturer to the wholesalers but without any order.
I know about the tutorial on Anylogic and I'm applying it, but it's not what I'm thinking about
I would like the demand from clients by Poisson distribution

Comment: You say here that "([you] don't know how to do [a Poisson distribution])" so here is a brief explanation and link in case that is a big part of the problem: "...can be used to estimate how many times an event is likely to occur within "X" periods of time." https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/poisson-distribution.asp

Comment: I know the formula, but I mean how to use it in Anylogic, I use this code `Orderwholesaler orderwholesaler = new Orderwholesaler(poisson(5.3), this);
Factorytrcuks truck = getNearestAgent(filter(main.factorytrcukses,
                   v -> v.inState(Factorytrcuks.AtFactory)));
                   
send (orderwholesaler, truck);` but I got this error "Description: The constructor Orderwholesaler(int, Wholesaler1) is undefined. Location: mémoire/Wholesaler1/request1 - Event"

Comment: Ha, shoulda figured that by the tag! Unfortunately, I am not well-versed in that area so the best I can do for you is provide this starting link: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/index.html. Is it just a workspace or does it have different code functionality?

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. To get the best help here, avoid asking "can you tell me how to do X". This will not work. Instead, ask "how can I fix Y", showing your trials already. Here is a summary on how to make SOF work for you as an AnyLogic user: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow